# LEFT JOIN in Big Query acting as RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been experiencing a strange problem. Sometimes when I am using `LEFT JOIN` in Big Query e.g in a dummy query like this:

`select A.id, A.some_col, B.another_col from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id`

and let's say table A has 10.000 entries and table B has 700 entries, I get 700 entries as a result. **Why doesn't it give me 10.000 entries (where 700 have full B. another_col and the remaining 9.300 have it as `NULL`)?**

Why is this so? It is performing like RIGHT JOIN. Does anybody understand it? What can I do to make it work correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have additional conditions that are filtering out rows (lots of things in a `where` clause would do this as would subsequent `inner join`s).  Personally, I have never experienced such an issue with BigQuery.

Comment: Please share a query we can reproducte

Comment: It seems to be working when I insert the conditions for the joined table immediately when joining particular table, not at the end of the query. Thank you @GordonLinoff. Also I needed to use ARRAY_AGG with the IGNORE NULLS option.

Comment: @talk-data, it will be appreciated if you can add your solution as an answer in this post, especially the conditions that made your query works. There are some details not so clear and other users can benefit with your solution.